# Como criar uma Connection Pool usando python e sqlAlchemy?

Tags: python

Olá !
Bem estou estudando python e comecei a procurar material sobre connection pool usando sqlalchemy mas infelizmente não encontrei nenhum exemplo na internet que mostra o processo de criação da connection pool usando python e sqlalchemy. Caso voces conheçam bons materiais por favor me indiquem. Desde já obrigado !

Comment: Porque não começa pela documentação? http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html

Comment: ja fiz mas não entendi direito

Answer (score 1):

Segue a pagina da documentação:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html

Veja um exemplo:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://me@localhost/mydb',
                       pool_size=20, max_overflow=0)
```

Caso queira só o sistema de pool do sqlalchemy e o drive nativo:

```
import sqlalchemy.pool as pool
import psycopg2

def getconn():
    c = psycopg2.connect(username='ed', host='127.0.0.1', dbname='test')
    return c

mypool = pool.QueuePool(getconn, max_overflow=10, pool_size=5)
# get a connection
conn = mypool.connect()

# use it
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select foo")
```

Comment: obrigado pela a ajuda !